# What's the easiest way to add flash to an html page to use with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

Is there a method in Jquery to add a flash movie easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [jQuery SWF object plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/), I'd start there.  I've used it several times, no issues...plenty of demos and documentation on the site there, it's pretty straight-forward.